# how to read the input values from a dynamic html table?

Tags: javascript, php, html

i have the following code to read the values from a regular input,

HTML:

```
     <tr>
  <th>Email:</th>     
    <td><input id="email"  name="email" onchange="EmailValidate()" maxlength="50"></td>
  </tr>
```

PHP:

```
      file_put_contents($file, "\nEMAIL:", FILE_APPEND | LOCK_EX);

  $ret = file_put_contents($file, $_POST['email'], FILE_APPEND | LOCK_EX);
```

in the same way, i am trying to read the input values from a dynamically generated html table, but i am getting an error,

HTML:

```
     <table>
  <tr>
  <th>Number of Models:<title="Number of Models"></th>

  <td><select id="numbermodels" name="numbermodels"       onchange="buildTable(this.value); buildTable4(this.value);">

  <option value="1">1</option >
  <option value="2">2</option >
  <option value="3">3</option >
  <option value="4">4</option >
  <option value="5">5</option >
  <option value="6">6</option >
  </select></td>
  </tr>

  <tr>
  <th>Number of heads per model:</th>
  <td>
  <table id="contentTable" border="1" name="contentTable">
    <!-- Fill table programmatically -->
      </table></td>
  </tr>
```

Javascript:

```
      function buildTable(val)
      {
     var myTable =document.getElementById("contentTable");
    var j=val;
        var rows = [];
    var cells = [];

     while (myTable.hasChildNodes()) {
     myTable.removeChild(myTable.lastChild);
      }


      for( var i = 0; i < 1; i++ )
       {
       rows[i] = myTable.insertRow(i);
       if(i%3==2)rows[i].addClass("every3rdrow");
         cells[i] = [];

       for( var x = 0; x < j ; x++ )
      {
        cells[i][x] =document.createElement((x==0)?"th":"td");
        cells[i][x].innerHTML = (x==0)?"<input id=t onchange=ty() name=t>":"<input     id=t onchange=ty()>";
        rows[rows.length - 1].appendChild(cells[i][x]);
        }
        }

         }
             buildTable();  

         function ty(){
      $ad = document.getElementById("t").value;
      if(!/^-?\d*$/.test($ad)) {
       alert("Number of heads per model value must be numeric!");
       } 
       }
```

for this also i wrote the similar PHP code, but i am getting the error Undefined index t,
PHP:

```
      file_put_contents($file, "\n Number of Heads per Model:", FILE_APPEND | LOCK_EX);

$ret = file_put_contents($file, $_POST['t'], FILE_APPEND | LOCK_EX);
```

what is the reason for this, what modifications can be done to be able to successfully read the input values from the dynamic html table ?

Comment: A few things: input IDs **must** be unique. You shouldn't use "t" for each input ID. Likewise, you need to make `t` an array. Change the `name=t` to `name=t[]`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A few suggestions:

1. Element IDs **must** be unique. You shouldn't use "t" for each input ID. You could change it to `id="t_$i_$x"` or something like that to make it unique.
2. You need to let your server side script know that `t` is an array. To get *all* of the values from the form submitted, change the `name=t` in the`<input>` element templates to `name="t[]"`.
3. Step 2 will break your validation function. I would change `onchange=ty()` to `onchange="ty(this)"`. You will then have to change your `ty()` function implementation to:

   ```
   function ty(el) {
       if(!/^-?\d*$/.test(el.value)) {
           alert("Number of heads per model value must be numeric!");
       } 
   }
   ```

   This consequently simplifies your function by removing the need to get the element again (you simply pass an instance of it in when you call it in the `onchange` event).
4. This isn't necessarily required, but it's a good practice to always enclose your HTML tag attribute values in quotations, as I've shown in my suggestions above.

Comment: thanks, it is working, but now to display the array contents in the text file, my code is:     $ret = file_put_contents($file, $_POST['t'], FILE_APPEND | LOCK_EX);
 
 $ret = file_put_contents($file, $_POST['t1'], FILE_APPEND | LOCK_EX);          but it is only displaying the first and last elements of the array with this above code, i think i have to use a for loop, but how to read the x value of the js function from php?